# Porting existing console application to Windows Azure

Tags: c#, javascript, azure

I have some console applications that communicate using WCF over TCP.  Is it possible/easy to port a console application to Windows Azure, or must the application be hosted in IIS/asp .net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you can use startup tasks in the config file for Azure.  That works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not really log into a Windows Azure machine and see the screen as you could do with a local server in your network I guess you should only develop server side components or IIS Hosted services and web applications exactly as you said.

you could get the Windows Azure SDK: [Windows Azure SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sdk/) and explorer the available templates and alternatives locally in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

A console application can be started from a role - web or worker - and communication to that app can be via the InputEndpoint (HTTP, HTTPS or TCP).

I worked on a project that spawned a console app from a worker role, the role fed workloads read from storage queues direct to a WCF service hosted in the console application - using tcp.